# How to go through an HTML table using PHP and get the data in each td?

Tags: php, export-to-excel, phpexcel, html-table

I am trying to use the PHPExcel class to export reports into excel file. What I really need to do is to go thru every row in the HTML table then place it into cells in an excel file.

I think PHPExcel has enough document to help me with created the excel file. But what I am not sure on how to do is to take an html table and break it so I can take every value and put it in an excel cell.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you use PHPExcel's HTML Reader? Load using HTML Reader, save using Excel2007 or Excel5 Writer, with no additional work needed at all

Comment: @MarkBaker How can I use the HTML Reader? where can I find samples on how to use it?

Comment: The HTML Reader is used in the same way as any other Reader, just use PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(<filename>) or instatiate the PHPExcel_Reader_HTML class and use its load() method

Comment: @MarkBaker Do you know of a full example of how to parse the html table so I can use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("myHtmlFile.html");

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("myExcelFile.xlsx");
```

but you could use your same basic logic for building the HTML from your report data, and just modify it to set cell values in a PHPExcel object. If you have an MVC, then its only the View that you really need to change.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. Where can I find documentation on how to point the reader to ready table with an id in a page? so if I have a table with id="extractableReport" then I can pass extractableReport and it will only export the table. I am sorry about all these question, this is my first time using this class or and reader.

Comment: You can't... The PHPExcel Readers require a filesystem file to read, not a url; if it's an external link, then you'd need to use curl to request the HTML and save it to file; if you're building the HTML yourself, then you send an extra argument and test for that to build the PHPExcel object rather than the html markup

Comment: It is internal link but I don't want to export all the data that is in the page. I open want to export a part of it.  so only export the table with in my internal page

Comment: In that case, you'd have to write your own parser, but the logic of the HTML Reader code should still give you the basis to do so

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mess with HTML but in `PHP`, i recommend [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

If you like jquery, you'll love it.

Example code:

```
$html = str_get_html('<table id="mytable"><td>cell ??</td><td>cell 2</td></table>');
$html->find("#mytable td:first-child",0)->innertext = "cell 1!";
echo $html;
```

done.

Answer (score -3):

You loop through it with jQuery

```
$('td').each(function(){
//do stuff here...
});
```

[jQuery API docs for .each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: I want to be able to do it with PHP because the PHPEcxel class is in PHP so I can't use jQuery